# Chrome heap profiler - What are 'Not Available' elements?

Tags: google-chrome, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

What does the 'Not Available' element represent? The fact that it shows up here means it still exists, then why can't I see any details? The Detached nods represent memory leaks, and to get rid of them, I need to know some information about them.

[image: Screenshot of my profiler]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Not available" means that object doesn't exist anymore (it was removed by garbage collector). Therefore, its details can't be displayed. It existed when you took the snapshot but it was already gone when you tried to get the details. Snapshots are capturing current state of the memory keeping only references to the live objects, they don't keep details. Since website/app is still working after snapshot was made, new objects can be created and old ones can be removed.

If you have a lot of these and profiling is getting harder due to huge amount of noise, try using "[Record Heap Allocations](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/revolutions2013/#toc-object-allocation)" instead.